# Como obter o nome da classe onde um bean será injetado?

Tags: java, spring, injeção-de-dependência

Estou configurando dois beans no arquivo `beans.xml` para injetar loggers em minhas classes.

```
<bean id="loggerFactory" class="company.LoggerFactory" />
<bean id="logger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-bean="loggerFactory" factory-method="createLogger" />
```

A configuração faz com que o método `LoggerFactory.createLogger` seja chamado e isso está funcionando corretamente.

O que eu quero saber é: como dentro deste método, eu obtenho a classe onde o objeto será injetado para colocá-la como nome do logger?

Answer (score 1):

Nunca vi injetar classe de log dessa forma. Não vejo necessidade alguma de injetar o log, já que deve haver uma instância para da classe.

Apenas crie um *logger* para cada classe num atributo privado através do método *factory*, assim:

```java
public class MinhaClasse {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MinhaClasse.class);
    (...)
}
```

A própria [documentação do log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) sobre a arquitetura aponta essa forma para recuperar loggers, sendo que a mesma instância será recuperada sempre que o parâmetro do método `getLogger` for o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Não sou versado nas maneiras Spring, mas por que não injetar apenas o `LoggerFactory` e criar o `Logger` no construtor do seu bean.

Isto é, algo como:

```
public class MeuBean {

  private final Logger logger;

  public MeuBean(LoggerFactory factory) {
     this.logger = factory.getLogger(getClass());
  }    

}
```

Certamente deve haver uma maneira mais 'Spring' para injetar diretamente a instância do Logger com as configurações que você deseja, mas, em tese, isto deve funcionar.

Ou ainda, dado que Loggers, em tese, são thread-safe, nem utilizar injeção de dependência.

```
public class MeuBean {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MeuBean.class);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como seria no Spring, mas com o padrão CDI seria assim:

```
@Produces
public static Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
  return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}
```

Você pode então consumir assim:

```
@Inject
Logger logger;
```

Comment: Eu já trabalhei com CDI, e por isso mesmo fiz essa pergunta. Sei que nele é possível dessa forma, mas no Spring não sei como fazer.